# How do I build clang that make use my own build libc++ by default?

Tags: c++, clang

I built libc++abi, libc++, glibc. so next I would like to build clang that use my own built library.
How do I build clang that make use my own built libraries by default?

Comment: I'd check for example [musl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl), an 'alternative' glibc implementation, and see how they integrate with clang/gcc/whatever.

Comment: Where is an example in musl website?

Answer (score 0):

Compile Clang with:

```
-DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++
```

Comment: I installed libraries in non-default location that `/home/myname/opt` how do I specify this directory?

Comment: It means that How to build clang to reference my own built C++ library when running `clang++ a.cpp` (no options)